# errors calling procedures when using the official "Neo4j Procedure Template" travers.findCoActors

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using this official neo4j template to understand how to write customized procedures https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template

I have loaded the compiled JAR file into the plugins directory on a neo4j container (community verison 4.4.4)

The customized function and aggregated function both works as expected. But when I call the customized procedure

```
MATCH (n:Person)
CALL travers.findCoActors(n.name);
```

I got an error

```
Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 2, column 1 (offset: 17))
"CALL travers.findCoActors(n.name);"
 ^
```

I understand that I need to use yield and return in the cypher query, but I am not sure what is the correct output format of the findCoActors based on the function definition in java. Not very familiar with all the stream APIs...

```
@Procedure(value = "travers.findCoActors", mode = Mode.READ)
@Description("traverses starting from the Person with the given name and returns all co-actors")
public Stream<CoActorRecord> findCoActors(@Name("actorName") String actorName) {

    Node actor = tx.findNodes(PERSON, "name", actorName)
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);

    final Traverser traverse = tx.traversalDescription()
            .depthFirst()
            .evaluator(Evaluators.fromDepth(1))
            .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(2))
            .evaluator(Evaluators.includeIfAcceptedByAny(new PathLogger(), new LabelEvaluator(PERSON)))
            .traverse(actor);

    return StreamSupport
            .stream(traverse.spliterator(), false)
            .map(Path::endNode)
            .map(CoActorRecord::new);
}
```

How do I make the query work?

Comment: It's similar to the question asked by you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603380/errors-calling-procedures-when-using-the-official-neo4j-procedure-template

Comment: In the `YIELD` statement use fields of the class CoActorRecord

Comment: Yes similar, but the return is in diff format and I am trying to learn more on stream API. Can you provide a concrete answer? @CharchitKapoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, of the neo4j Template, the procedure returns `Stream<RelationshipTypes>`, where the `RelationshipTypes` class is defined as:

```
public static class RelationshipTypes {
    public List<String> outgoing;
    public List<String> incoming;

    public RelationshipTypes(List<String> incoming, List<String> outgoing) {
         this.outgoing = outgoing;
         this.incoming = incoming;
    }
}
```

So when using this procedure, we use `YIELD incoming, outcoming`, basically the fields of the `RelationshipTypes` class. Similarly, now, in this case, you should yield the field of `CoActorRecord` class. For example, if the node is one field, then something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
CALL travers.findCoActors(n.name)
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Comment: Thank you. name does not work. But `node` works since that is the definition of the CoActorRecord. Now I have a much better understanding on how to use this. Please update your answer (yield node, return node) and i will accept it.